# Using biber 1.2 with MiKTeX

Tags: biblatex, miktex, biber

I'm having trouble compiling my document with `xelatex` using the latest version of `biber` (1.2) on Windows 7 x64 with MiKTeX. I just updated my MiKTeX packages.

As it appears that `biber` is not included with MiKTeX x64 I downloaded it manually from sourceforge.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letterpaper]{article} 

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    texencoding=utf8,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    style=nature,
    autocite=superscript,
    hyperref=false,
    maxbibnames=2,
    minbibnames=1,
    firstinits=true,
    indexing=true,
    abbreviate=true,
    sortcites=true,
    articletitle=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    isbn=false,
    eprint=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{Bunton2010}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bib file available here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/bib.bib

Here is the `biber` (1.2) output: http://pastebin.com/BQr4QBjr

Here is the output from the subsequant `xelatex` run after `biber`: http://pastebin.com/WvevfTKP

Note the error: `Package biblatex Warning: File 'mwe8.bbl' created by wrong version.`

Here is the broken pdf output: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3730003/mwe8.pdf

If I go back to the 0.99 version of `biber` everything works perfectly. 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 don't work.

Is there a way to solve this or should I just use `biber` 0.99?

Comment: You need to have version 2.1 or 2.2 of `biblatex` to work with `biber 1.2`.  See the compatibility matrix, Table 1, in the [biber documentation](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MWE works for me.

The log suggests you're using `biblatex` version 1.7, not the latest (2.2). I would check that you really did update all of your MiKTeX packages -- note that if some of them were installed as admin and some as user, you need to run the admin/user-level updaters separately. Also, you may have to run the (admin) updater twice, as I've found MiKTeX needs to first update some core parts of itself before it proceeds to update the other packages.